# Line Numbers for Errors not returning in SQL Developer when querying postgres

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper, line-numbers

As the title states, I am not getting the line numbers for errors in SQL Developer when I query a Postgres DB. Just a position error. Something like:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
Position: 135
```

I went into the preference and have the 'Show Line Numbers' enabled:

[image]

but they aren't showing. Is this an issue with Postgres in SQL Developer or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an issue with your editor, I tried 2 different editors on some bad SQL and both gave me a nice error message. Including the line and position of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Preference you set is related to line numbers here:

[image]

(that's the result of a mouse right-click).

What you're looking for is related to the way database reports errors. As far as Oracle is concerned, it works as expected:

[image]

As I don't use PostgreSQL, I can't comment it.

Comment: Thanks @Littlefoot I think you might be on to something. This is likely an issue with the database returning the error as opposed ot SQL Developer. I'll have a look at that and see if there's something that can be done in Postgres.

Comment: You're welcome; good luck!